# How to configure external Web Service (REST) for Authentication in WSO2?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm having separate Dotnet Web Service API to authenticate users. How can I configure it with WSO2 API Manager?

I have already configured WSO2 API Manager with external IDP (Keycloak). Is this is what im looking orcan be achieved in different way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to replace your user store(LDAP/AD/JDBC), with your Dotnet service, you might want to write a new custom user store manager extending the [CarbonRemoteUserStoreManger](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-userstore-remote/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.remote/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/user/store/remote/CarbonRemoteUserStoreManger.java) class. There, you should invoke your custom APIs to authenticate, retrieve users. Then you can add a secondary/primary user store with your [custom user store manager](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/managing-users-and-roles/managing-user-stores/writing-a-custom-user-store-manager/) implementation.

If you want to configure your Dotnet service as a Federated IdP in the API Manager server, you might have to write a [Custom Federated Authenticator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Writing+a+Custom+Federated+Authenticator) to communicate with your Dotnet service to authenticate the users. There you should be overriding the `initiateAuthenticationRequest` and `processAuthenticationResponse`.

**Editing the answer with the new context on issue**

In order to generate or validate tokens with an external party(Dotnet service), WSO2 needs to know the service contract of that service beforehand. How you fetch that information to the WSO2 APIM server is by writing an extension to the Key Manger service of the WSO2 APIM server.

By default WSO2 APIM has the implementation to talk to its own Key Manager component and the WSO2 Identity Server. But you need to write the logic (request/response templates) to validate tokens with your dotnet service. This is the official [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+a+Third-Party+Key+Manager) for this. These two Medium posts as well are written on that topic.

- [Blog 1](https://medium.com/@nuwandiwickramasinghe/using-wso2-api-manager-store-with-third-party-key-manager-50e2428ba76f)
- [Blog 2](https://medium.com/wso2-learning/understanding-wso2-api-manager-3rd-party-key-manager-integration-77a3677b1e9a)

Basically, you need to write a simple java extension project to the mentioned interface, so that WSO2 knows how to talk to your service. A [sample such implementation](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/apim-keymanager-okta) written for **Okta** as a Key Manager is pointed here.

Regarding your concern on validating both the token types;

Yes, it's possible using a custom key manager interface as described above. Once you receive the token at the API Manager side, if you can distinguish if the token was issued by your Dotnet service or by WSO2 itself from your Java logic (May be the token length), then your logic should divert the validation request respectively to WSO2 default Key Validation service (Call `super()`) or to your Dotnet service call. If you can't distinguish between the two tokens just by looking at them, then you can try both the servers to check if either can validate it. (There's a security vulnerability in that.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your information. At least now I got some idea to go further. My use case is I want to **authorize the request to WSO2 API Manager with token that is generated from separate server**. Kindly help me.

Comment: I believe you've configured keyCloak as a federated IDP. And now you want to delegate the token generation/validation part to your dotnet service, is it?

Comment: When I configured Keycloak, the request is redirecting to Keycloak login page. But in my case, suppose I'm **generating token from another REST API** and I want to authorize API requests using that token.

Comment: So your API Manager will use both REST API generated tokens and APIM internally generated tokens right? (There will be requests coming with externally generated tokens also with internally generated tokens. You want both to be validated)

Comment: Is it possible to authenticate both tokens ? **Only tokens generated from external souce, I want to be validated.**

Comment: Edited my answer to cater your exact requirement.

Comment: I have seen the links you have shared with me. In my case, I'm not having an **proper IDP Server**. I'm having simple authentication API. Using this method `processAuthenticationResponse`, it is possible to forward the request to my API server and set the `isBoolean` value to true